# .htaccess redirects not working with Angular 4

Tags: apache, angular, .htaccess, redirect

I know a lot of people ask this, but I have looked at all the answers and nothing is working.

I am sure the problem is I need to create a .htaccess file and add it to my dist because that is what the ISP console guide says to do.

I am using Angular cli and the build command:

```
ng build --aot --prod --base-href ./
```

I have added this .htaccess file to my app folder - the same folder as my index.html file. This is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I tried various snippets from various different answers on SO, I tried the snippet on the angular.io guide, I tried changing the base-href. Nothing seems to work and I can't even be sure it's being added properly to my dist in the build. What can I do?

Comment: Have a look at [this repo](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2)

Comment: I can't restart Apache coz I'm not serving it myself with a stack - I'm using node, npm and angular cli and uploading the dist to 1&1 with FTP? 1&1's guide says I won't be able to get at the httpd.conf file, but I can use a .htaccess file at the root of my app and it will affect all files in child directories.

Comment: Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories along the filesystem path?

Comment: In the node modules there are these matches for .htaccess:

Comment: node_modules/dom-converter/.npmignore:

Comment: node_modules/dom-converter/node_modules/utila/.npmignore:

Comment: node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mime-types/package.json:

Comment: node_modules/mime-types/README.md:

Comment: node_modules/mime-types/README.md:

Comment: node_modules/pretty-error/.npmignore:

Comment: node_modules/renderkid/.npmignore:

Comment: node_modules/utila/.npmignore:

Comment: The node modules are so complex I have no idea what most of it does!

Comment: It looks like .htaccess won't work with npm anyway? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 11):

After making a big fuss with the technical team of my hosting provider, they confirmed my .htaccess file was not being uploaded via my FTP client. It looks like I should have added it to the dist folder after the build. The code for the .htaccess file they added is just the same as one of the versions I tried before and it works fine:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://angular-doc.ru/guide/deployment

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```