# Angular after building can not refresh the page

Tags: angular

I have a project with angular4, after doing ng-build and run the build project i can not refresh or access to a page directly with his link a have a not found page error.

Comment: Is this about AngularJS 1.x (tag: `angularjs`) or Angular 2,3,4,5 (tag `angular`)? I guess you want `ng-serve` or `ng serve`

Comment: it about angular

Comment: are you trying to refresh by serving it through cli or from your backend ?

Comment: If you use `ng build` you need to publish it to some HTTP server. You can use the development server `ng serve` to serve it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem occurred because of no .htaccess configuration. When you deploy your dist on server.

Your solution is here.

[.htaccess redirects not working with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803855/htaccess-redirects-not-working-with-angular-4)