# How do we run Angular 2 application on Python Tornado?

Tags: python, angular, tornado

I want to run the Angular2 frontend on Python's Tornado backend. I tried  providing the index.html in Tornado's mainhandler, but it seems to me that the components are not being loaded when I run Tornado server. I don't want to run Angular frontend on ng server. Is there anyway to run Angular2 on Tornado or is it not feasible?

Comment: It is possible (or, at least [it was](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/52rf5v/angular_rc5_with_python_backend/) one year ago) Can you provide code, error messages, config files etc.?

Comment: @ForestG There's no error message. I created bundle.js and calling it from index.html. When I run `ng serve` command, the angular cli server starts and renders the component. When I try to run my python server, `python server.py` I can open the page without error, but the component is not getting displayed.

Comment: what can be read in your browser's console?

Comment: There's no error in browser's console. It's just not loading the app component. I don't know why. Is there any starter template of Angular + Python Tornado I could use.

Comment: @ForestG It's showing this error:

`WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /main.bundle.js (::1) 0.78ms`

And my tornado handler is this:

`r'/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './'}),
(r'/dist/(.*)', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './dist/'})`

Could you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Be aware, that paths for StaticFileHandler are evaluated relatively to working dir, not relatively to the py-file with paths. So, if you run your app from `/Users/username/project/` as `python tornado_app.py`, StaticFileHandler will serve files from `/Users/username/project/*` and `/Users/username/project/dist/*`. But if you run from `/` as `python /Users/username/project/tornado_app.py`, searched dirs will be `/*` and `/dist/*`.

Comment: That's right. That was the mistake. I fixed it and it's working smooth :) @Fian

Answer (score 0):

1) you have to host the Angular built files that are generated in the project's './dist' folder after running

> ng build --prod

in your Apache / NGINX web root folder.

2 )To link that front-end to the backend depends on your API calls. If you set your tornado web server to listen to calls on port 3001, all your requests to the backend in Angular have to be channeled to that port.

So, in the end, you should have your python3 /link/to/tornado/app.py running and listening in a terminal somewhere and your Web server serving the files that you eXtracted from the ./dist folder providing the front-end.

3) Hosting angular2+ apps on Apache needs you to configure an .htaccess file however, that will enable re-writing of the URL: Copy the file in the link [.htaccess redirects not working with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803855/htaccess-redirects-not-working-with-angular-4)